# Odd errors in bleach bit

Tags: permissions, bleachbit

When running Ubuntu and `bleachbit` as root I get this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/root/tmpLANpUQsZBUBAmqq-fQMbArbaj3QQbm1s03_Vax9iq6QHSa_cwHoLDBhJpdcRlq6dfF_X.FowA7_Sjw_R-hOVtTTK2iU5tLf3v34JYnyKbH0Y9Sg47eJ59CqZWQrcRKqFF-8x.jbPadCA2Ysr4Zlsa0Lbptstt28YKN2ZW_ohfIKloVM.Hy8fRZgPfAf2PiXodV5ajWME54 Lmxjied64gjyjt5oanmtZA13fRSQBro3-bUhKsipGsUeZkX'
```

Probably the gov as I've been inventing some pretty radical anti big brother systems or maybe just paranoia lol - what do you think?

Comment: use sudo to run this

Comment: @virusboy: The post states he is running as root.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a temporary file related to the "clean free disk space" option.  The last time this was reported was two years ago, so it does not happen frequently.  Also, it seems harmless (I am pretty sure the file does not exist now).

If you would like to help identify the issue so it can be fixed, please see https://bugs.launchpad.net/bleachbit/+bug/952055 . Please see the there questions in post #3.

If it is not reproducible, that would be good to know too.

Comment: This error actually destroyed the whole system, I was unable to boot after this :(  be very weary of bleach bit - great program but seems to be bleaching a bit too much looll   I'm now on my roughly 60th install of Ubuntu  hehe    and BTW i was ROOT

Comment: If you file a bug report at http://bleachbit.sourceforge.net/help I can follow up, but I am guessing this has to do with overwriting free space and was fixed a while ago in BleachBit 1.2.  (Ubuntu does not update BleachBit except with new releases of Ubuntu.)